# Error on Binary Search & Merge Sort Functions (with IO & command line)

Tags: java

I am experiencing an error. Running this program requires referencing the compiled jar file in a command line to specify the targets that must be found in the input file.

The error that is happening is any target string specified in the command line (that is present in the input file) gets an output of " not found", when it should be outputting " found on line {lineNumber}".

I went through the entirety of the class and frankly, I'm completely lost as to where this error occurs.

Any help is appreciated.

Main Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Search {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = null;
    int index = 0;
    String[] word = null;
    int[] lineNumber = null;

    // check number of command line arguments is at least 2
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("Usage: Search <input file> <target1> [target2...]");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // initialize Scanner
    in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

    // matches the end of a file character
    in.useDelimiter("\\Z");

    // puts entire file into one string
    String temp = in.next();

    in.close();

    // intialize arrays & plug elements in
    word = temp.split("\n");
    lineNumber = new int[word.length];
    populate(lineNumber);

    // sort String array
    mergeSort(word, lineNumber, 0, word.length - 1);

    // if multiple targets exist
    if (args.length > 2) {
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            index = binarySearch(word, 0, word.length - 1, args[i]);
            if (index < 0) {
                System.out.println(args[i] + " not found");
            } else {
                System.out.println(args[i] + " found on line " + lineNumber[index]);
            }
        }

        // if only single target specified in command line
    } else {
        index = binarySearch(word, 0, word.length - 1, args[1]);
        if (index < 0) {
            System.out.println(args[1] + " not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println(args[1] + " found on line " + lineNumber[index]);
        }
    }
}

// recursively halves arrays then plugs into merge function
public static void mergeSort(String[] word, int[] lineNumber, int p, int r) {
    int q;

    if (p < r) {
        // q is midpoint
        q = (p + r) / 2;

        // recursive stuff
        mergeSort(word, lineNumber, p, q);
        mergeSort(word, lineNumber, q + 1, r);

        // merge arrays
        merge(word, lineNumber, p, q, r);

    }
}

// merges sorted String arrays into one large sorted String array
public static void merge(String[] word, int[] lineNumber, int p, int q, int r) {
    // element ranges
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;

    // half String arrays to be merged
    String[] L = new String[n1];
    String[] R = new String[n2];

    // half int arrays to be merged
    int[] iL = new int[n1];
    int[] iR = new int[n2];

    // array indexes (for looping)
    int i, j, k;

    // plugging specific elements into new array
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = word[p + i];
        iL[i] = lineNumber[p + i];
    }

    // plugging specific elements into new array
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        R[j] = word[q + j + 1];
        iR[j] = lineNumber[q + j + 1];
    }

    // reset array indexes
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    // loop through entirety of elements
    for (k = p; k <= r; k++) {
        // if both arrays still have unmerged element(s)
        if (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            // if left array's element precedes right's element
            // lexicographically
            if (L[i].compareTo(R[j]) < 0) {
                word[k] = L[i];
                lineNumber[k] = iL[i];
                i++;
            } else { // if right's element precedes (or the words are equal)
                word[k] = R[j];
                lineNumber[k] = iR[j];
                j++;
            }
            // if only left array has unmerged element(s)
        } else if (i < n1) {
            word[k] = L[i];
            lineNumber[k] = iL[i];
            i++;
            // if only right array has unmerged element(s)
        } else {
            word[k] = R[j];
            lineNumber[k] = iR[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

}

// searches sorted String array and returns index of target (or -1 if not
// found)
public static int binarySearch(String[] word, int p, int r, String target) {
    int q;
    if (p > r) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        q = (p + r) / 2;
        if (target == word[q]) {
            return q;
        } else if (target.compareTo(word[q]) < 0) {
            return binarySearch(word, p, q - 1, target);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(word, q + 1, r, target);
        }
    }
}

// helper method: plugs numbers (in order) into an int array
public static void populate(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You must first isolate the bug, and a debugger can help you do this. You should be doing this *before* coming here by the way, and then if still stuck, show what you've done to debug the code, and why it's not helping you. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the below method. `String` should be compared with `equals()` method and use `trim()` method to avoid trailing spaces.

```
public static int binarySearch(String[] word, int p, int r, String target) {
    int q;
    if (p > r) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        q = (p + r) / 2;
        if (target.trim().equals(word[q].trim())) {
            return q;
        } else if (target.compareTo(word[q]) < 0) {
            return binarySearch(word, p, q - 1, target);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(word, q + 1, r, target);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not catch that silly mistake.